# how to search for an item a LIST of struct in c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following struct

```
 public struct Colors
 {
     public double MinV;
     public double MaxV;
     public string color;
 }
 List<Colors> ColorValues = new List<Colors>();
```

i need to retrieve the color of the element that has value located between Minv and Maxv.

i work as the following

```
i=0;
while (i < ColorValues.Count)
{
    if (value> ColorValues[i].MinV && value< ColorValues[i].MaxV) 
        Color=ColorValues[i].color;
    i++;
}
```

i need to replace this loop with fast searching way .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LINQ:

If you need all the structs that matches the criteria:

```
 var allThatFitsCriteria = ColorValues.Where(x => value > x.MinV && value < x.MaxV);
```

If you need only the first one (if it exists):

```
 var firstThatFitsCriteriaOrNull = ColorValues.FirstOrDefault(x => value > x.MinV && value < x.MaxV);
```

Comment: thanks its work .. please can give me some information on how to format it ..i don't know how to format it ..i test the follwing :      var firstThatFitsCriteriaOrNull = ColorValues.FirstOrDefault(x => value > x.MinV && value < x.MaxV);   and give me the results without using the first code with it

Comment: Not sure what you need, how do you want to format it? And what does "result without using the first code with it" mean? You just need to use the second row in my answer if you just need to find the first object with the correct criteria.

Comment: yes.. the second row in your answer solve my problem ...thanks i understand your code..

Answer (score 1):

An optimization would be to break out once you've found what you're looking for

```
i=0;
while (i < ColorValues.Count)
{
    if (value> ColorValues[i].MinV && value< ColorValues[i].MaxV) 
    {
        Color=ColorValues[i].color; 
        break; 
    }
    i++;
}
```